# how to I mass FIND code with Notepad++ (or similar tool)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have code that looks like

```
 '.Parameters.Add("p_Date", OracleClient.OracleType.DateTime).Value
```

or

```
 .Parameters.Add("p_Date", OracleClient.OracleType.DateTime).Value
```

The only difference is that one is commented and the other is not.

I want to search for all code in my project that aren't commented so I can focus on that

I don't mind downloading an IDE that you're familiar with to help me ONLY find those lines that are NOT commented.

[image: Notepad++ Screenshot getting no results]

Comment: Is the apostroph allways closed to the first dot? If not, could you give more examples and expected result?

Comment: Not really a "find" solution buy wouldn't setting the language to VB highlight the comments (green text) which would make them easy to find visually?

Comment: the ' is to indicate the line of code is a comment. I want to only find code that is not commented.

Comment: @Anu6is I am trying to find them and replace the text quickly. In the search results pane, the code is not color coded and there are more than 1300+ lines. I have to double click each entry than I can see if there was a ' or no ' before it. If this was a small project, I certainly wouldn't be asking for help

Comment: OK, I thought you were just scanning through the code and wanted to ignore comments. If you are dong a find and replace then regex is your best bet as suggested in the answer provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using Notepad++

The simplest way is to find with `Regular expression` checked.

```
(?<!')\.Parameters\.Add\("p_Date", OracleClient\.OracleType\.DateTime\)\.Value.*$
```

or

```
(?<!')\.Parameters\.Add.*$
```

To filter lines that don't begin with `cmd.`, add `(?<!cmd)` before `\.Parameters`, so the regex becomes:

```
(?<!')(?<!cmd)\.Parameters\.Add.*$
```

Comment: Can you explain the (?<!')\ part of the RegEx. I know I have code that is .Parameter.Add but when I literally copy and paste your code, I get 0 results. If I typed .Parameter.Add, I get 1300+ hits (including those lines that are commented)

Comment: @softwareisfun: `(?<!')` is called negative lookbehind. It's a zero length assertion that make sure we haven't an apostrophe before `.Parameter.Add.......` You get 0 result because of a typo, the parenthesis have to be escape, see my edit

Comment: please see the screenshot that I posted. I am still getting no results

Comment: @softwareisfun: Have you selected “Search Mode Regular expression”?

Comment: change `Parameter` to `Parameters`. Also, instead of the lookbehind, couldn't you use `[^']`?

Comment: @Default: You're right for `Parameters`, but `[^.]` consumes 1 character and lookbehind doesn't.

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question. can I also filter those lines that are not cmd.Parameters.Add in addition to '.Parameters.Add